# MybatisAutoConfiguration didn't create dataSource bean

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I have a SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE project,using `mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.jar`,and it works fine.

`mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.2.jar` will create the bean `datasource`  of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource].

But when I use `jar xvf` to extract the `jar` file,then I use `jar cvmf0 /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to recover the jar.Although the jar is the same,but it can't create the `datasource` bean.
  I use `java -Ddebug -jar` to run my project,find out the `spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar` is not on the top of classpath.
  Here is some error log:

```
MybatisAutoConfiguration:
   Did not match:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) **did not find any beans of typejavax.sql.DataSource** (OnBeanCondition)
   Matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory','org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)


 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
     at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
     at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:74)~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar!/:1.3.2]
     at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar!/:1.3.2]
     at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
     ... 108 common frames omitted
```

The application.yml is:

```js
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
  datasource:
    name: dataSource
    url: xxx
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    #type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
    driver-class-name: XXXX
mybatis:
   typeAliasesPackage: xxx
   mapperLocations: classpath:mybatis/mapper/*Mapper.xml
```

Comment: Please post application.properties or its equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.The application.yml is                                >spring:  
  profiles:  
    active: prod
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false  
  datasource:  
    name: dataSource  
    url: XXXX  
    username: XXX  
    password: XXXX  
    driver-class-name: XXXX   
mybatis:  
   typeAliasesPackage: com.jyyw.business.pojo  
   mapperLocations: classpath:mybatis/mapper/*Mapper.xml

Comment: dingjsh do not refine the question in comments. Modify the question itself with the information needed to provide the answer.